# Weird output on python IDE terminal

Tags: pi-3, serial, arduino

I am trying to get my Pi 3 communicated with arduino but am getting output which i can't understand.

My arduino code:

```
char dataString[50] = {0};
int a =0; 

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);              //Starting serial communication
}

void loop() {
  a++;                          // a value increase every loop
  sprintf(dataString,"%02X",a); // convert a value to hexa 
  Serial.println(dataString);   // send the data
  delay(1000);                  // give the loop some break
}
```

below is the python code.

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB1',9600)
s = [0,1]
while True:
    read_serial=ser.readline()
    s = str(int (ser.readline(),16))
    print(s)
    print(read_serial)
```

And my output looks like this.

2

b'01\r\n'

4

b'03\r\n'

6

b'05\r\n'

8

b'07\r\n'

10

b'09\r\n'

Why I am getting increment of 2 in iteration? Like i think i should get 10 and then its hex equivalent '0A'. But Its gets incremented. Why?

Comment: each loop of your python code is reading from the serial port twice,  (ser.readline() reads the next line)    Then you are printing those in reverse order. So thats why you see 2 then 1 then 4 then 3 ect.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reading it twice and only converting one to hex.   I took out the string conversion for clarity, but maybe you actually needed the hex string, in which case you could put it back

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB1',9600)
while True:
    raw=ser.readline()
    i=int(raw)
    h = int(raw,16)
    print(i)
    print(s)
```

Depeding on what your actually trying to do, this could still cause some issues trying to convert hex strings(from arduino) to something on the python side.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to help. But what's the purpose of 's = [0,1]' and second parameter in 'int' function i.e 16

Comment: oh, i actually didnt see the s=[0,1], that came from your original code, not sure what you intended it to be.   The second parameter on int(val,base) tells the int function what base(10-decimal, 16-hex, 2-binary, ect) the default is 10 which is way its not used when converting the first time